# Runtime config variable Google Deployment manager

Tags: google-deployment-manager

Cannot create a google deployment manager runtime config variable

```
resources:
- name: star-config
  type: runtimeconfig.v1beta1.config
  properties:
    name: star-config

- name: igurl_variable
  type: runtimeconfig.v1beta1.variable
  properties:
   name: igurl_variable
   value: 'trek'
   parent: $(ref.star-config.name)
```

I checked the logs and I see that the status is set to bad_request when I create the above deployment.

```
Audit log
status: {
   message:  "BAD_REQUEST"


  }
```

What could be the reason for the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try the with the properties fields as in the official documentation for both the [config](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/runtime-configurator/create-and-delete-runtimeconfig-resources) and [variable](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/runtime-configurator/set-and-get-variables) resources.

The resource file should be something like:

```
resources:
    - name: star-config
      type: runtimeconfig.v1beta1.config
      properties:
        config: star-config

    - name: igurl_variable
      type: runtimeconfig.v1beta1.variable
      properties:
       variable: igurl_variable
       text: 'trek'
       parent: $(ref.star-config.name)
```